# JavaScript AnchorTag.text returning undefined

Tags: javascript, getter

I have to take school names from this page: http://www.australianschoolsdirectory.com.au/search-result.php for a work and I do not want to do it manually so I wrote a script and put it into the console:

```
var schoolNames = document.getElementsByClassName( "listing-header" );
console.log( schoolNames[0].getElementsByTagName( 'a' ).text );
```

This code returns `undefined` but I expect to get the name of the first school.

How to make it properly if I think that this is done properly haha?

**Thank you!**

Comment: getElementsByTagName - the clue is in the signature. It can return multiple entries for the given tag. You'll have to loop through it, or grab the first one, if it exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling `.text()` on an array of results. The method that you used `getElementsByTagName()` returns an array. So when you want to get the text of such an element, say the first one, you'd use something like ths:

```
 console.log( schoolNames[0].getElementsByTagName( 'a' )[0].text );
```

Just like you have done in the first part of your code after getting an array of all elements which had a class name `var schoolNames = document.getElementsByClassName( "listing-header" );` and `schoolNames[0]`

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! Accepting answer as soon as possible!

Comment: @lolofon You're welcome, and thank you :-)